# Given a list of strings, each consisting of substrings separated by commas, how can I reorder the substrings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list of names in an excel file that I have copied into a text file. The format of the names is "last name, pre-names" where pre-names are first names (and middle names when applicable). In a handful of cases, there are two middle-names. How can I remove the comma and change the order of the names so that the first names (and middle names) come before the last name?

**Original:**

```
lastname1, firstname1
lastname2, firstname2 middlename2
lastname3, firstname3
```

**What I want:**

```
firstname1 lastname1
firstname2 middlename2 lastname2
firstname3 lastname3
```

**PS -** I teach labs at my local university and this is for a gradebook consisting of hundreds of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split, to divide the names on the comma:

```
for name in names:
    last, first = name.split(',', 1)
    print(first, last)
```

Sample data:

```
names = [x.strip() for x in """
    lastname1, firstname1
    lastname2, firstname2 middlename2
    lastname3, firstname3
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

Prints:

```
firstname1 lastname1
firstname2 middlename2 lastname2
firstname3 lastname3
```

If you need to read names from a file:

```
with open("file_location/file_name.txt") as f:
    names = f.readlines()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's helpful to others but I got this to work by trying:

    names = open("file_location/file_name.txt").read().splitlines()

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what environment (or application) you are using. 
For excel, I would simply import the text data and tell excel that it is comma delimited text. Here is how to do it (Microsoft link)
[Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857)